# How can I configure Undertow to add a charset to text/ content types?

Tags: java, undertow

I have a programmatically started Undertow server (not running as part of any container).

My static resources, served with a `ResourceHander` on a `PathResourceManager` are UTF-8 encoded, but the mime type sent by the `PathResourceManager` does not include a charset.

I'd rather not stoop to building a whole new `MimeMappings` table and installing it.

Is there any way to use a handler to add the `charset` to responses with a `CONTENT-TYPE` starting with `text/'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did this in my code:

```
handler = path()
        .addPrefixPath("/", resource(new FileResourceManager(webStaticDir, 1024))
        .setMimeMappings(MimeMappings.builder(true)
                .addMapping("html", "text/html;charset=utf-8")
                .build()));
```

Perhaps you can adapt it for your situation.

Comment: It seems I'd have to do this for every text/ mapping, which is a shame. Why on earth I can't just subclass MimeMappings I don't know.

Comment: Yes, they seem to have explicitly denied that without explaining why. Maybe you could submit a patch that makes the constructor more visible?