# Content type issue in Wildfly 10

Tags: wildfly, mime-types, wildfly-8, wildfly-10

I have a web application on Wildfly 10
and in the web application directory i have placed a zip file that I want to be downloaded when user clicks on the hyperlink.
On the UI I have

Snippet

```
<div class="tyDiv" onclick="window.open('request.getContextPath() + "/downloads/Installer.exe")%>','_self')">
</div>
```

It creates correct url like

```
"http://192.168.2.123:8080/comp/downloads/Installer.exe"


Content-Type:text/html;charset=UTF-8
```

This works in JBoss6 as expected . It downloads the exe file but in Wildfly it display all the junk characters on the screen as its content type is text/html

I tried setting mime type in standalone-full.xml but did not work.

```
 <mime-mappings>
    <mime-mapping name="css" value="text/css"/>
    <mime-mapping name="exe" value="application/octet-stream"/>
 </mime-mappings>
```

Comment: Could not reproduce this behaviour in vanilla Wildfly-10.0.0. My sequence of steps was ```cd  deployments; mkdir foo.war; echo bar > foo.war/bar.exe, curl -v http://localhost:8080/foo/bar.exe``` and the resulting ```Content-Type``` was ```application/octet-stream```. There must be something else. Check whether there's no custom `mime-mapping` in web.xml.

Comment: No. there is no mime-mapping instead I tried adding it into web.xml but It didn't work,

Comment: I suggest that you try my approach on **vanilla** Wildfly installation. Then try adding artifacts to your project piece by piece to see when it went wrong again.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation at [undertow.io](http://undertow.io/undertow-docs/undertow-docs-1.4.0/index.html#built-in-handlers) shows how to manually set the MIME type per response, eg. `exchange.getResponseHeaders().put(Headers.CONTENT_TYPE, "application/octet-stream");` while the file with the MIME type mappings might possibly be called `web.xml` (make sure the correct file is being referenced). Beside that, I could imagine that the servlet-filter may not be configured as it should - and it dispatches the request where they should not end up (have found https://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlet-filters/info). while this answer here even shows how to add MIME types at runtime: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38021097/549372 (ordinary is should nevertheless serve `application/octet-stream` while writing a binary stream to the output - which implies, that it also could be the result of a wrongful input stream).